# Problem sending multiple emails with Nodemailer - Subject not changing

Tags: node.js, express, email, asynchronous, nodemailer

I'am trying to send multiple emails with nodejs and nodemailer, I tried +50 methods until now and always the same result : the transporter sends the emails with different body BUT with the same subject,

I tried to send one by one insied the logic functions , the I switched to pushing all email payloads in an array and then call a function to send them and it's always the same : same subject (when I do console.log I see 3 different and correct email objects).

Here is my code (Books is a mongoose model) :

```
var TypesBook = [
  "Comic",
  "Action",
  "Adventure"
];

sendDailyEmails = () => {

  var emails = []; 

    Books.find({day: stringday}, (err, books) => {
      if (err) {
          console.log("error get books")
      }
      if (!stats) {
          console.log("books not found")
      }
      for (let i=0; i < TypesBook.length; i++) {
        let EmailPayload = {
          from: '',
          to:["test@test.test"],
          subject : "[Book "+TypesBook[i]+"] is availbale at day "+stringday
          }
        for (let j=0; j<books.length; j++) {
          if (TypesBook[i] !== books[j].Type) {
            continue
          } else {
            EmailPayload["html"] =
            'Hi' +
            "Your book "+TypesBook[i]+" is ready <br/><br />" +
            "details: "+books[j].Length.pages+" <br />"

            emails.push(EmailPayload)
          }
        }
      }
      sendMyNewEmails(emails);
  }).catch(err => console.log(err))

};

sendMyNewEmails = (tab) => {
  console.log(tab) // here I get 3 correct objects with correct subject and body
  tab.forEach(function(entry) {
    Email.sendMail(entry);
});
}

sendMail = async (payload) => {

  var mailOptions = {
    from: 'email@email.email',
    to: payload.to,
    subject: payload.subject,
    text: payload.text,
    html: payload.html   
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  });
}
```

And I changed it to this and still the same error :

```
sendMail = function(mailOptions){

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
     transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
        if (err) {
           console.log("error: ", err);
           reject(err);
        } else {
           console.log(`Mail sent successfully!`);
           resolve(info);
        }
     });
  });

}
```

**UPDATE :**

When I click on email details in the email received I see the correct subject but It comes to the inbox with wrong old subject (not even existing in the code).

Here the subject is wrong (all 3 emails are with that subject) 
[image: Here 3 emails with old / wrong subject]

Here inside the emails the subjects are correct : 
[image: Subject correct]

Answer (score 0):

Use closure function call(s) :

```
    var TypesBook = [
      "Comic",
      "Action",
      "Adventure"
    ];

    sendDailyEmails = () => {

      var emails = []; 

        Books.find({day: stringday}, (err, books) => {
          if (err) {
              console.log("error get books")
          }
          if (!stats) {
              console.log("books not found")
          }
          for (let i=0; i < TypesBook.length; i++) {

(function(idx){

  let EmailPayload = {
              from: '',
              to:["test@test.test"],
              subject : "[Book "+TypesBook[idx]+"] is availbale at day "+stringday
              }
            for (let j=0; j<books.length; j++) {
              if (TypesBook[idx] !== books[j].Type) {
                continue
              } else {
                EmailPayload["html"] =
                'Hi' +
                "Your book "+TypesBook[idx]+" is ready <br/><br />" +
                "details: "+books[j].Length.pages+" <br />"

                emails.push(EmailPayload)
              }
            }
          }
          sendMyNewEmails(emails);
      }).catch(err => console.log(err))

    };

    sendMyNewEmails = (tab) => {
      console.log(tab) // here I get 3 correct objects with correct subject and body
      tab.forEach(function(entry) {
        Email.sendMail(entry);
    });
    }

    sendMail = async (payload) => {

      var mailOptions = {
        from: 'email@email.email',
        to: payload.to,
        subject: payload.subject,
        text: payload.text,
        html: payload.html   
      };

      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if (error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
      });

})(i);

    }
```

Comment: the type of problem you have here is about a callback in a loop - variables lifecycle. the var i is already updated before the function is even placed in the queue. the solution is to use the kind of closure -- for(var i=;i<k;i++) (function(ii){ use ii instead of i here; })(i) --, if there's still a bug , that is somewehere else.

Comment: also , check for other variables, the result of the database query also may need to be defined in callback variables. try console.log for output first.

Answer (score 0):

```
const TypesBook = [
    "Comic",
    "Action",
    "Adventure"
];

const sendDailyEmails = async(stringday) => {
    try{
        const emails = []; 
        const books = await Books.find({day: stringday})
        for (let type of TypesBook) {
            const emailPayload = {
                from: ``,
                to: [`test@test.test`] ,
                subject : `[Book ${type}] is availbale at day ${stringday}`
            }
            for (let book of books) {
                if (type = book.Type) {
                    const newPayload = Object.assign({}, emailPayload);  // add this ine
                    newPayload[`html`] =                                //change this line
                    `Hi 
                    Your book ${type} is ready <br/><br />
                    details: ${book.Length.pages} <br/>`
                    emails.push(newPayload )                             //change this line
                }
            }
        }
        sendMyNewEmails(emails);
    }catch(err){
        throw err;
    }
};

const sendMyNewEmails = tab => {
    try{
        tab.map(entry => {
            Email.sendMail(entry);
        });
    }catch(err){
        throw err;
    }
}

const sendMail = async payload => {
    try{
        const mailOptions = {
            from: 'email@email.email',
            to: payload.to,
            subject: payload.subject,
            text: payload.text,
            html: payload.html   
        };

        const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)
    }catch(err){
        throw err;
    }
}
```